# Clarification of Regular/Normal spaces discussion in Munkres

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

In section 31 of Munkres' Topology text on regular and normal spaces, he often assumes for the theorems and interesting results that regular/normal spaces have closed point sets (i.e. the space is $T_1$).  But he also makes it clear that the implications $$ \text{normal} \implies \text{regular} \implies \text{Hausdorff}$$ are only valid when the topological space is $T_1$; because Hausdorff spaces are always $T_1$, but that normal and regular spaces need not be $T_1$ (e.g. a two point set in the trivial topology).  That much is clear.

However, when working some of the problems, specifically exercise 1, he makes no assumption that the space is $T_1$, just that it is regular.  I spent some time on this without assuming the space was $T_1$, which makes the solution quite simple in that case, but I was adamant that I couldn't assume that.  After spending too much time thinking about it I caved and looked at the solution, which assumed that one-point sets were closed ($T_1$).

Am I crazy or is Munkres only having us consider regular/normal spaces that are $T_1$ since those are the most interesting?

Comment: I haven't meet a single non T1 space (with the exeption of the explamples following the definition of a T1 space) so i guess one can live happily with only T1 spaces...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re not crazy: you just didn’t look closely enough at his definition. If you look closely at the definition of regularity at the beginning of Section $31$, you’ll see that the property is defined only for spaces in which singletons are closed, i.e., only for $T_1$ spaces. What he calls *regular* is what I (and other sensible people :-)) call $T_3$, so that the $T_k$ properties form a real hierarchy. Unfortunately, his definition is not uncommon, though [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_axiom#Main_definitions) uses the definitions that I prefer while noting the variants. Both usages are common enough that you simply have to learn which one any given author uses.